# MS Access making navigation options on form NOT mutually exclusive

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm creating a navigation form where some of the navigation buttons simply apply filters to the subform. Problem is right now each option is exclusive, i.e. I can select staff either by branch OR by job title. How can I make the options NOT exclusive so that I can apply multiple filters at once?

EDIT just to add. I have no knowledge of VBA so I'm trying to do this using the graphical interface and of macros. If it can't be done using these tools then fine, I'll find a different solution.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16067840/edit) your question to provide more context. When the user clicks one of these "navigation buttons" what does your existing code actually do? ...set the `.Filter` property of the form to a new value, perhaps?

Comment: The subform shows all the employee records by default. Each of the buttons in the navigation pane applies a filter to the subform. I'm just trying to figure if there is an option to allow it to apply more than one filter simultaneously.

Comment: Do you want it to filter by branch `or` title or branch `and` title?

Comment: Yes. I want to be able to apply any combination of filters by clicking on them.

Comment: I need to create a quick and dirty prototype and I just don't have the time to stop and learn a new language. Also being a prototype I want to implement functionality in as simple a manner as possible. It doesn't need to work, it needs to look as if it works. But of course it would be better to have a multiple select option rather than having me telling the customer that "hey, we could implement this with a multiple select option".

Answer (score 1):

If you *replace* the `.Filter` property on a form (or subform) with a new value then the previous filter goes away. If you *append* a new clause onto an existing `.Filter` string, e.g. by changing...

```
[Branch]="Main"
```

...to...

```
[Branch]="Main" AND [Title]="Manager"
```

...then the new filter applies both criteria.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean I'd have to create a navigation control for every possibly combination of filters?

Comment: @spacitron Not necessarily. A very common approach is to have a radio button on a search form to select "must match all" (so any selected criteria are logically `AND`ed), or "must match any" (so any selected criteria are logically `OR`d).

Answer (score 1):

This solution requires a moderate amount of VBA (I can't think of a solution that wouldn't require it).  Store the user's choices in module level variables and then apply your filters using a master `ApplyFilters` subroutine.

For example, give each checkbox an AfterUpdate event. This event will do 2 things:

1. Set the *module* level variable with the user's selection
2. Start the *ApplyFilters* sub

Since all the user's choices are now stored in module level variables, the *ApplyFilters* can see them all.  It will:

1. Take all the module level variables and creates a master string (hint, if you need a Placeholder, use `1=1`)
2. Apply that string as your subform's filter.

Other notes:
Accessing your subform's controls from the main form is simple. To change your subform's filter to the string NewFilter, try:

```
 Forms!MyMainFormsName!MySubFormsName.Filter=NewFilter
```

Comment: How about - and I don't even know if such thing is really possible - if I added a series of check boxes, and each check box would select a navigation option, which in turn applied the filter? Since multiple checkboxes can be selected at once this would mean that in turn multiple navigation options could be selected at once. I mean, obviously at this point it would make more sense to use checkboxes directly, but connecting them to the subform is something else I've been having problems with.

Comment: Good news, I think we're on the same page. I rephrased my answer. Does it make more sense now?